# Arabic Characters not printing in java application developed with NetBeans IDE

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, unicode, arabic

I have created a desktop application in JAVA using NetBeans IDE. Application can write data to a file. I use Arabic characters in my application and When i Run the Application directly from NetBeans, I can write The Arabic characters to a file without any issue. But when i run the .jar file in dist folder outside NetBeans, it shows '????' instead of Arabic font. I will be grateful if some one can help me to find a solution.[image: The screen shot is given below]

This is my Custom Logger Class:

```
public class MLogger {

   private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger( MLogger.class.getName() );
   private static   FileHandler fh; 
   private static SimpleFormatter sf;

   public static synchronized  void writeLogToFile(String message){
        try {
             fh   = new FileHandler("D://wblogs/wblog.txt", true);
              // true forces append mode
            sf= new SimpleFormatter();
            fh.setFormatter(sf);
            log.addHandler(fh);



            log.log( Level.INFO,message);


        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MLogger.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (SecurityException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MLogger.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

and I use the method :

```
MLogger.writeLogToFile("محمد اقبال");
```

Comment: How are you writing the data? Just using a logger? Which encoding are you expecting the file to be in? UTF-8 or some other encoding?

Comment: I use a custom Logger Class

Comment: How do you run the jar? Is this on a linux or windows box? What is the OS default charset? What if you specify java default encoding: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/362006/180100

Comment: I run it in windows.

Answer (score 2):

You have different encodings in use between running in NetBeans, and from commandline. A quick fix for your problem is to add

```
fh.setEncoding("UTF-8"); // and catch UnsupportedEncodingException
```

to the code you showed.

A better fix for your problem is:

1. Don't use `java.util.logging` it's horrible, and nobody uses it
2. Don't create "custom code" for logging. You don't need it. This is especially true if you switch to a modern logger like `SLF4J/Logback`.

Comment: Thank you very much.
fh.setEncoding("UTF-8") works fine.